# Unable to install the libi2c-dev:armhf in ubuntu18.04

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, dpkg, architecture

I want to cross_compile a c program, which communicates with the device "/dev/i2c-0" in SAM_A5d27 board. For which I needed the libi2c-dev package in my Ubuntu-18.04 desktop. As the SAM_A5d27 has arm architecture, therefore I have added the armhf architecture to "dpkg" and tried to install the libi2c-dev in armhf but I got error as "E: Unable to locate package libi2c-dev:armhf". The following steps I had followed. Please have a look and help me to solve this problem.

```
    gp@guru-hp:~$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
    gp@guru-hp:~$ sudo apt-get update
    Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
    Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                                    
    Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                    
    Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                     
    Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]                                       
    Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/kicad-5.1/ubuntu bionic InRelease                               
    Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                              
    Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]                    
    Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]          
    Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]          
    Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]                           
    Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]          
    Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]          
    Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]          
    Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]          
    Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]          
    Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]          
    Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]          
    Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]          
    Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]                           
    Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]          
    Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]          
    Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]                                
    Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]                                
    Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages [968 kB]          
    Ign:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages                   
    Get:28 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted armhf Packages [8,360 B]
    Get:28 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted armhf Packages [8,360 B]
    Get:28 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted armhf Packages [8,360 B]
    Ign:28 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted armhf Packages
    Ign:32 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe armhf Packages         
    Ign:33 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse armhf Packages       
    Ign:34 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main armhf Packages           
    Ign:35 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages     
    Ign:36 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe armhf Packages       
    Ign:37 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse armhf Packages       
    Ign:38 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/main armhf Packages           
    Ign:39 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe armhf Packages       
    Ign:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages              
    Ign:28 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted armhf Packages       
    Ign:32 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe armhf Packages         
    Ign:33 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse armhf Packages       
    Ign:34 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main armhf Packages     
    Ign:35 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages
    Ign:36 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe armhf Packages 
    Ign:37 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
    Ign:38 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/main armhf Packages   
    Ign:39 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe armhf Packages
    Ign:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages       
    Ign:28 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted armhf Packages  
    Ign:32 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe armhf Packages      
    Ign:33 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse armhf Packages    
    Ign:34 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main armhf Packages  
    Ign:35 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages
    Ign:36 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe armhf Packages
    Ign:37 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
    Ign:38 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/main armhf Packages
    Ign:39 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe armhf Packages
    Ign:40 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages
    Get:41 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [651 kB]
    Err:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages
      404  Not Found [IP: 2403:8940:ffff::f 80]
    Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages [442 kB]
    Get:43 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main Translation-en [211 kB]
    Get:44 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [38.5 kB]
    Get:45 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [17.6 kB]
    Get:46 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [41.5 kB]
    Get:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted armhf Packages [3,968 B]
    Get:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted armhf Packages [3,968 B]
    Get:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted armhf Packages [3,968 B]
    Get:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted armhf Packages [3,968 B]
    Get:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted armhf Packages [3,968 B]
    Get:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted armhf Packages [3,968 B]
    Get:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted armhf Packages [3,968 B]
    Get:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted armhf Packages [3,968 B]
    Get:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted armhf Packages [3,968 B]
    Get:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted armhf Packages [3,968 B]
    Get:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted armhf Packages [3,968 B]
    Ign:28 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted armhf Packages
    Ign:32 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe armhf Packages
    Ign:33 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse armhf Packages
    Err:34 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main armhf Packages
      404  Not Found [IP: 2403:8940:ffff::f 80]
    Ign:35 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages
    Ign:36 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe armhf Packages
    Ign:37 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
    Err:38 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/main armhf Packages
      404  Not Found [IP: 2403:8940:ffff::f 80]
    Ign:39 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe armhf Packages
    Ign:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted armhf Packages
    Ign:59 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe armhf Packages
    Ign:60 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse armhf Packages
    Ign:40 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages
    Ign:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted armhf Packages
    Ign:59 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe armhf Packages
    Ign:60 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse armhf Packages
    Ign:40 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages
    Ign:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted armhf Packages
    Ign:59 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe armhf Packages
    Ign:60 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse armhf Packages
    Err:40 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages
      404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
    Ign:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted armhf Packages
    Ign:59 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe armhf Packages
    Ign:60 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse armhf Packages
    Fetched 252 kB in 5s (45.9 kB/s)
    Reading package lists... Done
    E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2403:8940:ffff::f 80]
    E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2403:8940:ffff::f 80]
    E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2403:8940:ffff::f 80]
    E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
    E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
    gp@guru-hp:~$ 
    gp@guru-hp:~$ sudo apt-get install libi2c-dev:armhf
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package libi2c-dev:armhf
    gp@guru-hp:~$
```

I have verified the availability of the package libi2c-dev in ubunt package manager site. https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libi2c-dev

Answer (score 0):

The armhf package isn't in the universe repository. I found it at http://ports.ubuntu.com

Here's what I did to get version 4.0-2:

```
$ wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/universe/i/i2c-tools/libi2c-dev_4.0-2_armhf.deb
$ sudo dpkg --force architecture --install ./libi2c-dev_4.0-2_armhf.deb
```

This does throw up an error message:

```
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: package architecture (armhf) does not match system (amd64)
(Reading database ... 52515 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ./libi2c-dev_4.0-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libi2c-dev:armhf (4.0-2) over (4.0-2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libi2c-dev:armhf:
 libi2c-dev:armhf depends on libi2c0 (= 4.0-2).

dpkg: error processing package libi2c-dev:armhf (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libi2c-dev:armhf
```

It does provide the required library, though, and puts it into a sensible place in the file system so your amd64 host isn't messed up.

After this installation, my cross-compiled project that referenced -li2c linked properly.